# Handling @error messages over blade livewire files, not showing after updating to livewire 3.0

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 10. After updating from livewire 2.x to 3.0 @error messages on forms not showing.

Doing test, I check mi blade file that calls the livewire file, and error shows there.
But error variables on livewire file not reaching.

I expect to see @error messages validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhD9L.png)

Take it from:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation

You might be wondering if you can use Laravel's "FormRequest"s. Due to the nature of Livewire, hooking into the http request wouldn't make sense. For now, this functionality is not possible or recommended.

On livewire version 2.x Laravel FormRequest validation or other's works fine, as so @error @enderror.
Since livewire 3.x version Laravel Formrequest or other validation's still working but:
@error @enderror not working.